# can't get the session from session store in node.js connect-mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

I am using connect-mongo to store my session data, blew is the code to start my express server and mongodb session.

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);

var sessionStore = new MongoStore({url: config.sessionStore}, function() {
                          console.log('connect mongodb session success...');
})

app.configure(function(){
    ............
    //  // cookieParser should be above session
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
     // express/mongo session storage  //  
    app.use(express.session({ 
                      cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
                      store: sessionStore,
                      secret: config.sessionSecret,
                  key: 'express.sid',
                          clear_interval: 3600
                                          }));
    ............
})
```

I have looked into the chrome browser and can of course see my session key- 'express.sid' and corresponding value.

when the user logs into my server, I want to get their session data from my mongodb session store. However, session store query the session data with no error but just showing the output **null**.

```
var connect = require('express/node_modules/connect')
, parseSignedCookie = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie
, cookie = require('express/node_modules/cookie');

function fileUpload(req, res) {

    var sid = req.cookies['express.sid'];
    var sessionID = parseSignedCookie(sid, config.sessionSecret);   
    console.log('fileUpload  ',req.ip, sid,sessionID);
    // output the session value as expected 

    // but session store can't query the session data, no error but just no values
    sessionStore.get(sid, function(err, session){
          // access to session
           if(err) console.log("session store err".red,error);
           else console.log("sessionStore auth  ".green+session);
    }); 

    res.send(200);
};
```

What goes wrong with my node, or any another things I missed?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use mongo for your session storage? Often people end up using Redis for session storage since it is much faster and you need to read the session data on every page load

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you'd want to retrieve the session data from the database yourself? The whole point of using a session store is that Express and the store (de-)serialize the session for you automatically and make it available through `req.session`.

Comment: well, in working with socket.io, during the authentication phrase, it is needed to to get the session uid and use this to query whether the user is authenticated or not. And the problem is socket.io can't authenticate with session, that is why I use the code above to test